# Publish to device from Android Studio no longer working

Tags: testing, android-studio, gradle, publish

So iv spent the last couple of weeks building my first app in Android Studio and all has gone well. Successfully launched on device through whole testing / Dev phase.

I got to a point where I was happy and proceeded to build a signed APK using Build->Generate Signed APK.

This was successful and now I have a published APK.

I have since noticed a spelling mistake (Rookie error!).

I have corrected the spelling but now when I click the "play" button to launch a test version it appears to be building the app on outputs a big stack trace ending with the following...

> BUILD SUCCESSFUL
>
> Total time: 1 mins 21.581 secs 13:15:46: External task execution
>   finished 'build'.

But then that is it, no offer to view on device like during the initial build stage. (no device popup)

What am I missing to get this to publish onto a test device again?

Any help or pointers are appreciated, I'm new to this Gradle thing, I have a feeling its something to do with that but I don't know where to start and Google doesn't seem to find anything useful to me :/

Comment: hi mate, thanks for the response, i think it was just a bit of a glitch / fault with my PC, I closed the program and opened it again with no results, and on the off chance I tried restarting the computer and this fixed my problem, I could publish to device once again!